# NodeJS server changing keyname of JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, server

I am sending POST request to my server via $.ajax and my JSON object is experiencing some problem in server

Client Side code:

```
var someArr = ["ayush","hehehe"];
        var data = {
            "profileType": "",
            "location": someArr,
            "centerPref": 0,
            "subjects": []
        };
        console.log(data.location);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/upload/furtherDetails",
            data: data    
        })
```

But on console logging req.body I get this output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your json data is urlencoded. In order for it to be parsed into a rich json object you have to use a special library to do so.

Here's how to do it with the body-parser package:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Difference it makes:

```
-- with: bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) --

{ profileType: '',
  location: [ 'ayush', 'hehehe' ],
  centerPref: '0' }

-- with: bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }) -- 

{ profileType: '',
  'location[]': [ 'ayush', 'hehehe' ],
  centerPref: '0' }
```